# linux- How I do run to any command with parameter with execlp function in C

Tags: c, linux, function

I want run a command write execlp function within c file in linux.
I want to run the following command :

`ls -l`

I can do ls command as follows :

`execlp("/bin/ls" , "ls", NULL)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the option to the parameter list:

```
execlp("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);
```